# Write list and value in same row csv

Tags: python, csv

I have several values and severals list with differents length. 
I'd like to write them in the same CSV row.

i.e. 
I have these values

```
a=1234

b=["John","Bryan","Johnny"]

c="Value"

d=["Comedy","Action"]
```

As output I'd like a csv file like this :

```
[1234;"John";"Bryan";"Johnny";Value;Comedy;Action]
```

So far I coded this

```
resultFile = open("DNA_Movie.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
wr.writerows([imdb_id, genre, actors])
```

But the result is like this:

```
1234
"John","Bryan","Johnny"
"Value"
"Comedy","Action"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `writerow` and combine each element together into a single `list`:

```
wr.writerow([a] + b + [c] + d)
```

Some of the elements need to be wrapped in brackets to turn them into a `list` with a single element.

Answer (score 0):

As TigerhawkT3 said you'll want to use `writerow` and also when you're instantiating your csv.writer set the `delimiter` to ';'.